# React Native - get data from return

Tags: function, react-native, return, asyncstorage

in my App.js i want to return the Token and a RememberMe const from the AsyncStorage. The 'Get' function is in another file.
I cant read the Data in the App.js from the function and i hope you can help me.

This is my code:

const.js

```
export const getToken = async () => {
    const Token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('IN_Token');
    const ReMe = await AsyncStorage.getItem('RememberMe');
    return (Token, ReMe);
}
```

App.js

```
export default () => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);

    React.useEffect(() => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setIsLoading(false);
        }, 3000)
        getToken()
    }, [])

    if (isLoading) {
        return <Splash/>
    }
    if (getToken) {
        return <HomeStack/>
    }

    return (

        <AuthStack/>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you should return a object :

```
export const getToken = async () => {
    const Token = await AsyncStorage.getItem('IN_Token');
    const ReMe = await AsyncStorage.getItem('RememberMe');
    return {Token, ReMe};
}
```

Second getToken is a async function, it returns a promise you have to wait for it to resolve

```
export default () => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = React.useState(true);
    const [tokenObj, setTokenObj] = React.useState({});
    React.useEffect(() => {
        getToken().then(res=> {
           setIsLoading(false);
           setTokenObj(res)
        })
    }, [])

    if (isLoading) {
        return <Splash/>
    }
    if (tokenObj.Token) {
        return <HomeStack/>
    }

    return (

        <AuthStack/>
    )
}
```

Try this